# Attempting to browse to a virtual directory gives a 503 error

Tags: iis

I created a Virtual Directory using Visual Studio 2015 called "License Manager" for development.  At some point, it became corrupted and started giving me 503 errors no matter what I did.  So I created another Virtual Directory called "License" and it worked perfectly.  So I went back to IIS and removed the "License Manager" directory, recycled IIS, and tried to create it again using the exact same steps I used to create "License".  Still getting the 503 errors.  Is there any way to clean up a corrupted IIS database (or at least completely purge a virtual directory?)

Edit: Yes, I've uninstalled and re-installed IIS.

Answer (score 1):

OK, for anyone else who might run into this: the problem was that I made some ACL reservations for this URL when it was a self-hosted web service.  The commands I ran to grant permission were:

```
$user = [Environment]::UserName
netsh http add urlacl url=https://+:443/"License Manager"/"Data Model" user="$user"
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:80/"License Manager"/"Data Model" user="$user"
```

Now, oddly, I had a script to remove these entries when I switched to an Application Service (IIS hosted), that looked like this:

```
netsh http delete urlacl url=https://+:443/"License Manager"/"Data Model"
netsh http delete urlacl url=http://+:80/"License Manager"/"Data Model"
```

The problem is, the root directory is created implicitly for you, so you need to purge the root ACL list as well.  This fixed the problem:

```
netsh http delete urlacl url=https://+:443/"License Manager"
```